# Java concurrency - Is this efficient?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of what you would like to do");
System.out.println("1 = Manually enter Options");
System.out.println("2 = Use a text file to pick from pre-existing models");
System.out.println("3 = Exit ");


Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    runType = sc.nextInt();
    if(runType > 3) {
        throw new badValue(999, "Not the valid input");
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
} catch (badValue e) {
    e.correctBadValue(runType);
} 

switch (runType) {
case 1:
    Thread a = new SelectCarOption();
    a.run();
case 2: 
    Thread a2 = new BuildCarModelOptions();
    a2.run();
case 3:
    System.exit(1); 

}
```

}
}

So basically, I'm trying to run a program where the thread that is running is determined by a variable runType. If runType is one value, a certain thread will run and if it is the other, the other will run. Is my approach the most efficient? Will it turn out to give any errors?

Comment: Why are you starting thread1 and then stopping it when you figure out it is not the correct thread? Just start the thread that you need to run. Also, are you sure that you need threads for this?

Comment: `sleep(` is by definition a waste of time.

Comment: you are btw doing it wrong. `.start()` starts the thread. Don't call `run()` or there is no thread and `run` is exectued in place in whatever thread you are.

Comment: Even if you have a problem of this kind, you should use a Lock, the thread aquiring Lock will run and others will wait.

Comment: The code appears to take pains to not actually execute concurrently, so the question that arises is do you actually need concurrent code and threads?  As written, you could replace your code with direct calls to 2 methods which would be far more clear.

Comment: I have updated my code, will it work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A programmer had a problem. He thought to himself, "I know, I'll solve it with threads!". has Now problems. two he

**A)**

you can replace

```
    Thread thread1 = new SelectCarOption();
    thread1.start();
    thread1.join();
```

by directly executing whatever `run` does since the thread that starts the thread just waits.

```
calling thread   | new thread

   start() ---->
                   run()
   join()        <---
```

does the same thing as

```
   run()
```

Now we can simplify your code to:

```
   if (runType == 2) {
       doCarModelOptionsIO();
   } else {
       doSelectCarOption()
   }
```

And you have a much more efficient way.

**B)**

Don't call the `run()` method on a thread. Every method called directly is executed in place in your current thread. `Thread` has the `start()` method that you call which then calls `run()` from within that new thread.

Comment: thank you i appreciate the clear answer. I decided to do your approach.

Answer (score 5):

Long story short, no, this is not how you want to do things.

1. `thread1.run()` doesn't start a new thread, it just calls the code in `run()` on the current thread. What you want is `thread1.start()`.
2. `thread1.sleep(5000)` will not make `thread1` sleep, it will make the *main* thread sleep. `Thread.sleep` is a static method that affects the current thread, and the fact that you're using an instance variable to invoke it (rather than the more traditional `Thread.sleep(5000)`) doesn't change that.
3. It makes no sense to start `thread2` and then immediately join to it. You may as well just invoke its code directly on the main thread. (Which is what you're doing right now, since you're invoking `thread2.run()` instead of `thread2.start()`.)

I'm not sure what your end goals are, but this sounds like a case for plain old polymorphism. Create a `Runnable` and assign it to one of two concrete implementations, depending on the input; then just invoke `run()` on it. Something like:

```
Runnable selectStrategy = (runType == 2)
    ? new CarModelOptionsIO()
    : new SelectCarOption()

selectStrategy.run()
```

If you need a result from this action, you could use a [`Callable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) (don't let the package name confuse you; there's nothing inherent to concurrency in that interface) or even create your own interface, which lets you give more meaningful names to the methods (`call` and `run` are pretty unhelpfully generic).

Comment: You're still using `Thread.run`. That doesn't start a new thread. It's just a plain ol', normal, standard method invocation. Also, you really shouldn't be catching the NPE and ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your code. and to let you know, the code you have written does not spawn a new thread at all. Few thing to note:

Thread.sleep() is a static method. The below code is misleading:

```
try {
  thread1.sleep(5000); //stops thread1 to run different thread 
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

You have started thread1 in the main thread and then called sleep method using the newly created thread. But this is not gonna help you. It makes the main thread sleep not thread1. To make thread1 sleep you need to call sleep method within the run() of this thread1 class.
Moreover, sleep() is a static method and should not be called using thread instances, it is misleading.
Also stopping a thread does not necessarily mean it will invoke the other thread. Just remember when it comes to threading, very little is guaranteed.
One more thing :

```
thread1.run(); // This is incorrect
```

use `thread1.start()`

Directly calling run() method does not start a new thread. You need to call start() method to start a new thread. Calling run method directly will execute the contents of the run method in the same thread(from where it is invoked)

Answer (score 0):

Overall, your code is confused. I suggest [reading the concurrency tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) if you haven't already. Review them if you have read them. Maybe do a few yourself, **then** come back to this problem.

You say:

> If runType is one value, a certain thread will run and if it is the other, the other will run.

To do that you need something like this...

```
    if (runType == 2) {
        Thread thread1 = new SelectCarOption();
        thread1.run();
        try {
            //join blocks until thread 1 terminates. We don't know that it
            //ever will give your code
            thread1.join(); //stops thread1 to run different thread 
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread thread2 = new CarModelOptionsIO();
        thread2.run();
        try {
            //blocks again, until thread 2 is done running.
            thread2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {

        try {
            thread1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //start some other thread here since runType is different?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes in your class. First you are using the method run() instead of start(). Second, you should start both threads for your sleep() make sense. That a look on the Oracle Java Se tutorial online to see the basics of Java Multithreading model, that will help a lot.